# jQuery: find the previous sibling with a class name?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<div class="buildExMain">
    Select An Option
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="buildExDrop">
            <p class="pSelection">Number 1</p>
            <p class="pSelection">Number 2</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to `show();` the `.fa` element when a `.pSelection` is clicked on.

I tried this jquery code with no luck:

```
$(document).on('click','.pSelection', function(e){
    //This doesn't work////
    $(this).prev(".fa").show();

    //doesn't work either///
    $(this).prevAll(".buildExMain.fa:first").show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) selects the *previous sibling*, which the `<i>` element isn't. You want:

```
$(this).closest("div.buildExMain").find('i.fa').show();
```

or, since its parent *is* a sibling of the `<i>`, you could use `.parent()` and `.prev()` together like:

```
$(this).parent().prev('i.fa').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

you element is child of div element and you want to locate element just above it .

```
 $(this).parent().prev(".fa").show();
```

Comment: Well, he doesn't *have* to use `.closest()`. There are other ways to traverse the DOM.

Comment: @j08691- i am going to write about parent but i think closest is enough for that ...but thanks for your answer with all the ways..i keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand the *this* scope

by looking your code that *this* element can only be one of those `<p>` elements so if you search for the sibling of *this* it will only look for the other `<p>` element you have to do something like

```
$('.fa').show()
or
$(this).parent().prev().show() //this is because it's exactly the previous sibling
or
$(this).parent().prev('.fa').show()
```